# Правописание личных окончаний глаголов

Tags: окончания

они высп_тся
Нужно определить, какую букву следует вставить на месте пропуска. Для этого нужно поставить глагол в начальную форму. Спать оканчивается на -ать, значит, глагол первого спряжения, значит, окончание -ут/-ют. Но, как известно, правильнее будет написать "они выспятся". Почему такая несостыковка?

Answer (score 2):

[Вы́спаться](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) — правильно *они вы́сп**я**тся*.
У многих глаголов приставка **вы-** принимает на себя ударение, в результате чего возникают затруднения в написании.
В этих случаях сомнительное окончание рекомендуется проверять бесприставочным словом:  вы́спаться — спать (вы́сп**и**шься — сп**и**шь; вы́сп**я**тся — сп**я**т).

Приставочные глаголы относятся к тому же типу спряжения, что и бесприставочные глаголы, от которых они образованы. Поэтому для того, чтобы определить тип спряжения глагола **вы́спаться**, надо определить тип спряжения глагола **спать**.
Это глагол с ударными личными окончаниями (***спишь, спим, спят***), тип спряжения у таких глаголов определяется по окончаниям. *Спать* – глагол второго спряжения, поэтому и глагол *выспаться* тоже относится ко второму спряжению (правильно: выспишься, выспятся).

[Правописание глаголов](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.32)

Answer (score 2):

Выполняя это задание, вы должны в первую очередь УВИДЕТЬ ударную приставку ВЫ-, отбросить её и посмотреть, какая буква пишется в ударном окончании и перед -ТЬ.

В такого рода глаголах приставка ВЫ- перетягивает на себя ударение. Отбрасываем её, получаем СПЯТ с ударной Я, и все личные окончания будут ударными. В этом случае, чтобы правильно написать окончание, не надо определять спряжение, ударные окончания вы всегда напишете правильно.

Ср.: ВЫЛЕТИШЬ. То же самое. Убираем ударную ВЫ- , остаётся летИшь, летИм, летИте и т.п. Хотя инфинитив ЛЕТЕТЬ оканчивается на -ЕТЬ (но Е тоже ударная, и тоже никаких проблем в написании).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нечего проверять по спряжению, потому что окончание везде ударное: *спл**ю**, сп**и**шь, сп**и**т, ... сп**я**т*. Раз *сп**я**т* - значит, *выспятся*.